# how to use multibinding in the text property in a listBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, multibinding

I have a listBox that bind to a class in my view model. This class has many properties but I would like to show two of them in my listBox.

I see that example ([post](http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/04/12/concatenatefieldsmultivalueconverter.aspx))

The main code is this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
               <TextBlock.Text>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mvc}"
                                ConverterParameter=", ">
                     <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                     <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                  </MultiBinding>
               </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>

      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

My problem is that when I try to use it, the  is not avaliable in my axml. So I can't continue with the code.

Why Have I not avaliable the Multibinding?

My axml is:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,41,0,0" Name="lsbPersonas" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Personas}"
                 SelectionMode="Extended" Height="112">


            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <Multibinding ???? (I don't have this avaliable)
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have added an appropriate binding converter to your project (like the static resource `mvc` from the code sample).

Fortunately it isn't even necessary. You could set the MultiBinding's [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property instead:

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
        <Binding Path="LastName"/>
        <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: Yes, I have a wondow resources in which I have my converters. However the problem is not that, but that I can't avaliable de Multibinding. I have only have ![CData[, ?, /TextBlock.text, cmd:, i: and x:

Comment: You mean in IntelliSense? Well, sometimes it doesn't show you *everything*  you could write. Simply write the MultiBinding, it will compile.

Comment: It's true, I have use the code, compile and works. Thank you very much.